# Python | How to overload __getitem__ and __setitem__ to allow for double indexing?

Tags: python, indexing, operator-overloading

so I can't figure out how to overload the `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` operators for double indexing in my class. I'm trying to iterate over a user-defined instance attribute, which is a collection of 2-tuples, for example `self.coeffs = ((6,2),(5,5),(1,8))`, where the first index is a 2-tuple and the second index is either the first or second item in the 2-tuple. For the previous object, `self.coeffs[2][0]` would be `1`.

I'm pretty sure I understand how to set up the methods for a single index, but I don't know how to get Python to consider the second index call.

Here's a section of my class (`self.coeffs` is the instance attribute made from user-defined tuples):

Where the class is first calling the index operators:

```
`def __str__(self):
       if self.__coeffs[0][1] == 0:   #TypeError: 'int' object isn't subscriptable
            return str((self.__coeffs)[0][0])`
```

My current index operators:

```
`def __getitem__(self, idx):
     for t in self.__coeffs:
         if t[1] == idx:
             return t[0]
     if idx not in [t[1] for t in self.__coeffs]:
         return 0


 def __setitem__(self, idx, value):
     for t in self.__coeffs:
         if t[1] == idx:
             t[0] = value
     if idx not in [t[1] for t in self.__coeffs]:
         self.addterm(value, exp)`
```

Also, I have to have the single parameter `idx` for `__getitem__`, I can't pass in more than that single argument. If anyone knows how to work around this or has any suggestions, it will be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: The `__getitem__` method can only see _one_ "layer" at a time, so if you need to return a value that is accessed again by an index, you should ensure that the `return 0` is replaced with `return [0]` so that any failure for `self.coeffs[2][0]` will at least see the `0`.  Really though, it would be more useful if you have more example usage of your class, with the output you expect, because as it is written it is difficult to tell what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @metatoaster I appreciate the response 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object that is returned, by the first `__getitem__` needs to implement the `__getitem__` too. The error occurs because at one point you return `0`, which is an integer and as the error says: 'int' object is not subscriptable.

To answer your question more precise. The implementation depends on the data that is stored.

**The simplest case: 2d array**

If you store a 2d in your class, you can return it like this:

```
# self.data[[0,1],[0,1],[34,234,234,234]]
def __getitem__(self, idx):
   return self.data[idx]
```

You have to make sure, that you always return another list.

**Other objects**

If you want to return another object of a class, that object needs to implement the `__getitem__` method.

```
class A:
    # self.data = [1,2,3,67]
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self.data[idx]

class B:
    # self.data = [A(), A(), A()]
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self.data[idx]
```

The same things apply to the `__setitem__` function

Comment: Thank you so much!